# Display header and footer of a CSS template properly after the browser window is resized

Tags: html, css

I'm using the following CSS to display a basic web template with header, footer, left sidebar and right sidebar.http://jsfiddle.net/k5g0frvt/

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 800px;
    margin: 0;
}
#container {
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -90px;
}
#north {
    height: 170px;
    background: pink;
}
#west {
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
    background: #fff;
}
#content {
    margin-left: 120px;
    margin-right: 120px;
    background: lemonchiffon;
    padding: 1px 1em;
}
#east {
    float: right;
    width: 120px;
    background: palegreen;
}
#south, #container:after {
    height: 90px;
}
#south {
    background: #777;
    border-top: 7px solid #000;
}
.clearfix:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
}
```

This works fine with a sticky footer but when for example, I display some images in a table inside the content bar something like the following,

```
<div id="container" class="clearfix">
    <div id="north"></div>
    <div id="west"></div>
    <div id="east"></div>

    <div id="content">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><img alt="Not available" height="310" width="210"/></td>
                <td><img alt="Not available" height="310" width="210"/></td>
                <td><img alt="Not available" height="310" width="210"/></td>
                <td><img alt="Not available" height="310" width="210"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="south"></div>
```

and after displaying this table, if the browser window is resized then, the header and footer are not displayed properly as can be seen in the following picture.

[image]

The header and the footer go smaller than the actual page content, when the browser window is resized. This should not happen.

How to fix them?

Comment: not define `#west #east` style `height`

Comment: 'min-width: 800px;' applies when all content is resized undefined

Comment: There is no height in those classes `#west` and `#east`. Removing `min-width: 800px;` makes no difference.

Comment: only the percentage refers to the window when the scroll is not present

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/k5g0frvt/embedded/result/ I don't see it

Comment: That happens, when the browser window is resized which cannot be noticed in the jsfiddle. @Brian

Answer (score 0):

**here css**

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
#container {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.box{
    width: 100%;
    min-width:860px;
    text-align:center;
}
#north {
    height: 150px;
    background: pink;
}
#west{
    width: 120px;
    height: 160px;
    background: cyan;
    float:left;
}
#east{
    width: 120px;
    height: 170px;
    background: palegreen;
    float:right ;
}
#content {
    width: 800px;
    margin:auto;
    background: lemonchiffon;
}
#south{
    height: 300px;
    background: gray;
    border-top: 7px solid #000;
}
```

**here html**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="north" class="box">Content</div>
    <div id="west" ></div>
    <div id="east" ></div>
    <div id="content" class="box">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><img alt="Not available" height="310" width="210"/></td>
                <td><img alt="Not available" height="310" width="210"/></td>
                <td><img alt="Not available" height="310" width="210"/></td>
                <td><img alt="Not available" height="310" width="210"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="south" class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The value of `min-width` varies depending upon the elements displayed on the page. In my real application, it requires about `1320px`. The header and the footer fit the page appropriately, when I used `html, body {display: inline-block; min-width: 100%;}` but I don't know whether it is legal to use `display: inline-block;` in `html, body {}`.